# Model attribute for specified view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Im using `Spring Boot MVC` with `Thymeleaf` as the view layer.
I have specified fragments like `header`, `alert` and `footer`. I would like to create dynamic navigation based on my mappings.

Is it possible to create model that is set to specified view? It would be cleaner to have specified models only in specified views

EDIT:

Lets say i have something like this in my `index.html`.

`<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header">Test</div><h1>HelloWorld</h1>`
I would like to have access to my model only in `header` fragment file and no in `index.html`.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. If you're using something like Thymeleaf Layout Dialect, you might be looking for `data-th-with` on the `html` element.

Comment: I'm looking for something like `ModelAttribute` in `ControllerAdvice` that can be reached only in specified view (for example in header.html)

Comment: What do you mean "reached"? Can you provide a concrete example of how this would work?

Comment: I will add my answers as edit in question

Comment: No, what you are looking for is not possible (the reasoning follows). You have a composite view (primary view generation file `index.html` loads a secondary file `header.html`). Spring Boot is based on Spring MVC where each request is tied to a unique controller method. The implementation of this method decides what view should be loaded. The model is populated before the view is loaded, so the entire model is available to all the files that make up the view.

Comment: Apache Tiles maybe ?